# How can I half fill my circles to white?

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

```
def redCircles():
    win = GraphWin("Patch2" ,100,100)
    for x in (10, 30, 50, 70, 90):
        for y in (10, 30, 50, 70, 90):
            c = Circle(Point(x,y), 10)
            c.setFill("red")
            c.draw(win)
```

This is my code and the output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `Circle`, create two `Polygon` objects each representing ½ the circle and fill one with red and the other with white. Alternatively, you could fill a whole `Circle` with red and then create a white `Polygon` object representing the half you want filled with white.

Comment: @martineau It's an assignment, [here it is a recent, previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27137304/2749397)

Comment: @gboffi, should I delete my answer? I just saw your comment now.

Comment: @JaredWindover It's a good answer, and it's probably too late. Imho you shouldn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this and it works for me.

```
from graphics import *

def redCircles():
    win = GraphWin("Patch2" ,100,100)
    for x in (10, 30, 50, 70, 90):
        for y in (10, 30, 50, 70, 90):
            c = Circle(Point(x,y), 10)
            d = Circle(Point(x,y), 10)
            if x in (30, 70):
                r = Rectangle(Point(x - 10, y), Point(x + 10, y + 10))                
            else:
                r = Rectangle(Point(x - 10, y- 10), Point(x, y + 10))
            c.setFill("red")
            d.setOutline("red") 
            r.setFill("white")
            r.setOutline('white')
            c.draw(win)
            r.draw(win)
            d.draw(win)

if __name__=='__main__':
    redCircles()
```

We're drawing filled circles, then rectangles over half of them, and then outlined circles to get the outlines back. The if checks which column we're in.

Comment: thank you you've furthered my knowledge in python (y)

Answer (score 0):

Below is my (bloated) rework of @JaredWindover's solution with modifications.  First, as much graphic object setup as possible is done before the nested loops, taking advantage of Zelle's `clone()` method.  Second, it fixes a bug, hard to see in the small, where half the outline in the circles is black instead of red.  Finally, unlike Jared's solution and the OP's code, it is scalable:

```
from graphics import *

RADIUS = 25

def redCircles(win):
    outline_template = Circle(Point(0, 0), RADIUS)
    outline_template.setOutline('red')

    fill_template = outline_template.clone()
    fill_template.setFill('red')

    horizontal_template = Rectangle(Point(0, 0), Point(RADIUS * 2, RADIUS))
    horizontal_template.setFill('white')
    horizontal_template.setOutline('white')

    vertical_template = Rectangle(Point(0, 0), Point(RADIUS, RADIUS * 2))
    vertical_template.setFill('white')
    vertical_template.setOutline('white')

    for parity, x in enumerate(range(RADIUS, RADIUS * 10, RADIUS * 2)):

        for y in range(RADIUS, RADIUS * 10, RADIUS * 2):

            fill = fill_template.clone()
            fill.move(x, y)
            fill.draw(win)

            if parity % 2 == 1:
                rectangle = horizontal_template.clone()
                rectangle.move(x - RADIUS, y)
            else:
                rectangle = vertical_template.clone()
                rectangle.move(x - RADIUS, y - RADIUS)

            rectangle.draw(win)

            outline = outline_template.clone()
            outline.move(x, y)
            outline.draw(win)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = GraphWin('Patch2', RADIUS * 10, RADIUS * 10)

    redCircles(win)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
```